# Gatsby-image: provide the right image size to different resolution

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am struggling with Gatsby-image to provide the right image size to different resolution. I have an image of size 1920x367 (width x height) and the issue is visible when window size is small (mobile for example) because gatsy-image is using an image of 490x92 to cover a container of 437x354.

[Here](https://imgbox.com/Uz2H9koL) you can see the image when window size is big. [Here](https://imgbox.com/BDW18bs7) when window size is low.

**GraphQL query**:

```
configHowWeWork: file(relativePath: { eq: "howwework/howwework-header.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1920, maxHeight: 367) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
        }
    }
}
```

**Gatsby-image**:

```
<div className="intro intro-page intro-container">
    {configHowWeWork.childImageSharp.fluid && (
        <Img
            className="intro-background"
            fluid={configHowWeWork.childImageSharp.fluid}
            alt="alt"
        />
    )}
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**:

```
.intro-container {
    position: relative;
}

.intro-background {
    position: absolute!important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Question**: How can I avoid to request an image of size 490x92 (same initial aspect ratio) and instead provide one that can fill up 437x354 (cropping or clipping is what I want, but without zooming in) without streching height.

**What I already tried**:

1. I tried to use FILL as fit in gatsby query to overcome aspect ratio constraint, but it did not the trick.
2. Using [presentationSize](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type).

Thanks for you answer.

**EDIT**: THe only one solution found is to create a square image with dimension `max(width, height)`, but in my case is always width. In this way I achieve good quality with low and high resolution (mobile and desktop, for example), but I am wasting too much resource:

- With a desktop resolution image generated is 1920x1920, but container dimension is 1920x367.
- With a mobile resolution is not so unbalanced, but still bigger the necessary with height.

I am sure I am missing something because could not be so difficult to just create a responsive wide hero image.

**EDIT 2**: I can not get why image quality is good if I switch to mobile resolution with Responsive Design Mode in Firefox, but quality is not good if I use a resolution comparable to previous mobile but without Responsive Design Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overcome issue with 3 images and art direction, I am no able to do better than that.

**First, query images**:

```
headerLarge: file(relativePath: { eq: "image-L.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1920, webpQuality: 100) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
        }
    }
}
headerMedium: file(relativePath: { eq: "image-M.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 900, webpQuality: 100) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
        }
    }
}
headerSmall: file(relativePath: { eq: "image-S.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 500, webpQuality: 100) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
        }
    }
}
```

**Create sources array**:

```
const sourcesImage = [
    {
        ...headerSmall.childImageSharp.fluid,
        media: '(max-width: 500px)',
    },
    {
        ...headerMedium.childImageSharp.fluid,
        media: '(max-width: 900px)',
    },
    {
        ...headerLarge.childImageSharp.fluid,
        media: '(max-width: 3840px)',
    },
];
```

**Use sources with gatsby-image**:

```
<Img
    fluid={sources}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fluid images in Gatsby stretches across the container (e.g: for a container whose max width is `800px`, the automatic sizes would be: `200px`, `400px`, `800px`, `1200px` and `1600px`). If you want more control over which sizes are output you can use the `srcSetBreakpoints` parameter. Applied to your code:

```
configHowWeWork: file(relativePath: { eq: "howwework/howwework-header.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1920, srcSetBreakpoints: [ 400, 600, 960, 1280, 1920 ]) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `srcSetBreakpoints` is an array of integers with your custom values. This will provide a `srcSet` to your image with the desired sizes.

You can play with them to check which ones fit your requirements. In addition, I would remove the `maxHeight` parameter since it may cause you a limitation query because it restricts the aspect ratio of your image in small sizes, it's automatically calculated using the `maxWidth` provided.

Another hack that may help you is to change CSS `object-fit` to `contain` property in some resolutions to fit 100% of the container.

References/Interesting readings:

- [Gatsby Image Documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-image/#images-that-stretch-across-a-fluid-container)
- [[gatsby-image] Possible to pass in custom "sizes" value?](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5516)
- [[gatsby-image] Scale image to height of container](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4898)

Comment: He, thanks for takeyour  time for answer this question. I already tried to use only `maxWidth` to avoid aspect ratio constrain (actually what I pasted before it is a left over). Also, if I add srcSetBreakpoints does not resolve my issue, because gatsby-image (actually sharp) is still generating an image with aspect ratio (400x76 as size). Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you just set a `minHeight` value?

Comment: Without `srcSetBreakpoints` and `object-fit: contain;`, right? `minHeight` on image wrapper or `<img>`?

Comment: Try adding to with `imgStyle` but does not work, still same result.

Comment: Can you try another GraphQL fragment?

Comment: You mean fluid or fixed? Or just without `_withWebp`?